# Restrict aggregation to results of filter

Tags: filter, elasticsearch, aggregation

Given a set of documents that have a given value in one field, I want to know how many documents there are that have each value for a second field.

I've tried to do that with a terms aggregation with the following query:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "filter": {
        "term": {
            "field1": "value"
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "field2" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "field2" }
        }
    }
}
```

but the returned counts show the number of documents with each value for the second field in the *whole index*, and not restricted to those documents with a given value for the first field.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you tried using filtered query?

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
           "query": {
                "match_all": {}
           },
           "filter": {
               "term": {
                  "field1": "value"
               }
           }
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "field2": {
           "terms": { "field": "field2" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filters.html) recommends using filters instead of queries for filtering by exact values? Another issue: how to apply multiple conditions? Filters offer an [`and`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-and-filter.html), did not found that for queries...

Comment: I'm wondering the same myself... So basically we should stop using filters alltogether if we need to use aggregations? That doesnt seem right

Comment: @VitorM Yes, aggregations always operate inside a query scope (with `match_all` by default).

And no, you shouldn't stop using filters with aggregations. There's a [Filtered Query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) to narrow down scope with performance and caching of filters and then there's a [Filter Aggregation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) to filter aggregation buckets for its subaggregations.

Combining these two one can make really powerful filtering.

Answer (score 9):

There is a comparison here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_post_filter.html

In short, your top-level filter is acting like a post_filter in the link. To filter, then compute the aggregate, you need to use a query.

If you are concerned about the performance hit because of the computation of scores in queries, you can look into constant score queries which basically a filter-wrapper query.